# OpenCSV package doesn't exist gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, opencsv

I'm trying to create a CSV writer and saw OpenCSV was a good option. 
However I've been having endless trouble trying to import it and use it.

This is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.1'
}
```

I have it imported at the top of my code like:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
```

Code snippet (likely not relevant as I've only just started on it)
This error happens when I try and compile my code with javac myapp.java though command line.

```
    File file = new File("../");

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);
        writer.close();
```

The error I get is on line 1 (the import of OpenCSV) saying com.opencsv does not exist. 
Intellij asked if I wanted to add it to my classpath at one point, to which I said yes. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project also to no avail.

Comment: do you want to use this livrary in your project java code? or in your gradle scripts?   and do you see the dependency when executing `gradlew dependencies` ?

Comment: Yes I want to use this library in my code to write a CSV file. And I see it when I run that gradle command

Answer (score 0):

in your `build.gradle (Module: app)`, add this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.8'
    ...
}
```

and in your `build.grade (Module: project)` (or `settings.gradle` for newer android versions), make sure to have **mavelCentral()**

for example:

```
  repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```